# Letters/digits are being deleted as I type. Why?

Tags: keyboard

This isn't a development issue, but I had no idea where other to turn to than here: My issue is that whenever I type, whatever I have typed dissapears.

I was working on getting C++ SDL from Lazyfoo working for Android development, when halfway through the process my laptop's keyboard started acting up. Deleting commands I was typing in cmd, deleting code, etc. I know it's not an issue with the 'insert' key, so that's out of the question.

Does anybody know what the issue here can be? Looking on google only gives me issues with people having pressed 'insert' while typing in MS-Word.

I'll try a USB keyboard in a sec and update you in on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you spill something on the keyboard?  Maybe your delete key is sticking.

My laptop had the battery swell up recently and interfere with the keyboard.  It's possible maybe your battery is going.

The usb keyboard sounds like a good thing to try.  It may still happen if your laptop keyboard is being triggered somehow though.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My keyboard seems to be acting back to normal now, and I haven't done anything. I'll have to keep a close eye on it.